# Calling the current user in a Django view and template

Tags: python, django, django-views

I have a view where a chat channel is created between two users. I want to notify the user when a message is sent (who it came from) but I'm having trouble accessing the current user (the user who is logged in and sending the message). In the view below I have a 'to_user' whose name is displayed properly, however, the 'current_user' is not displaying.

Here is my views.py

```
@login_required
def create_channel(request, to_user_id):
    to_user = get_user_model().objects.get(pk=to_user_id)
    try:
        channel = Channel.objects.get(users=request.user, users__id=to_user_id)
    except Channel.DoesNotExist:
        channel = Channel.objects.create(
            channel_name='{from_user}-{to_user}'.format(from_user=request.user.username, to_user=to_user)
        )
        channel.users.add(request.user)
        channel.users.add(to_user)
        client = get_client()
        service = client.chat.services(settings.TWILIO_CHAT_SID)
        twilio_channel = service.channels.create(channel.channel_name)

        channel.twilio_chat_id = twilio_channel.sid

        twilio_channel.members.create(identity=request.user.get_twilio_user_id())
        twilio_channel.members.create(identity=to_user.get_twilio_user_id())
        channel.save()
        #email the to_user when they receive a message
        to_user = to_user
        current_user = request.user
        to_user_email = to_user.email
        user_email = current_user.email
        html_message_to_user = render_to_string('send_message_to_user.html', {'user': current_user,
                                                                            'to_user': to_user,
                                                                            'channel': channel,
                                                                            }
        #send email to the to_user
        send_mail(current_user.first_name + ' has sent you a message', plain_message_to_user, 'x@x.com', [to_user_email], fail_silently=False, html_message=html_message_to_user)
        mail_admins('A message has been sent', 'A message has been sent to ' + to_user.first_name + ' from ' + current_user.first_name, fail_silently=False, )

    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('chatapp:twilio', kwargs={'pk': channel.pk}))
```

The email is sending properly however the 'current_user' first_name is not showing up. I have also tried to simply put 'user' or 'request.user' and these don't work either. I'm not sure how to get the current users name to display in the email message or in the email template.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: Maybe you should try the `.format()` way instead of the `+`. So, the send_mail should look like: `send_mail('{} has sent you a message'.format(current_user.first_name), plain_message_to_user, 'x@x.com', [to_user_email], fail_silently=False, html_message=html_message_to_user)`. Don't know if that's gonna fix it though

Comment: that also didn't work..